# How do I refer to the list being mapped in Io?

Tags: dictionary, iolanguage

Io allows an optional parameter referring to the index of a list item. How do I use that to refer to the list being mapped, for example, I could write:

```
testList := list(1,2,3,4)
testList map(i,v, if(testList(i+v), v, v-1))
```

and the result would be `list(1,2,3,3)`

But what if I want to write that without creating the variable testList? How do I refer to the list that I'm mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using an intermediate name, you cannot access the receiver inside the map. The map is evaluated within the context of the caller, i.e., where your call to `list(1,2,3,4)` would be made.